# Filling space/tab separated, empty columns with 0

Tags: regex, perl, file, sed, awk

i have a huge file and as an output some columns doesn't have a value, i need to fill these columns with 0 for further analysis. I can separate the columns with space or tab, now below it is seen separated with tab.

[image]

Comment: Just a question, have you examined the last blank column in an editor? Is the column data (not the delimeter) an actual \t ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is really a job for a CSV parser, but if it has to be a regex, and you never have tabs within quoted CSV entries, you could search for

```
(^|\t)(?=\t|$)
```

and replace with

```
$10
```

So, in Perl:

```
(ResultString = $subject) =~ 
s/(    # Match either...
   ^   # the start of the line (preferably)
   |   # or
   \t  # a tab character
  )    # remember the match in backreference no. 1
  (?=  # Then assert that the next character is either
   \t  # a(nother) tab character
   |   # or
   $   # the end of the line
  )    # End of lookahead assertion
/${1}0/xg;
```

This will transform

```
1   2       4           7   8
    2   3       5   6   7
```

into

```
1   2   0   4   0   0   7   8   
0   2   3   0   5   6   7   0
```

Comment: "...if it has to be a regex..." - the original poster never mentioned using a regex?

Comment: @mfontani: Oops. Of course... - @plusplus: Yes, he did, it's the first tag he used.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker,  perl -p -e "s/(^|\t)(?=\t|$)/${1}0/xg" file , does not seem to work, any idea? zero's are just put next to the column members

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know Perl (I got the code snippet from RegexBuddy which translated my regex into Perl code), so I can't tell what might have gone wrong. It does expect the file to be tab-separated. Can you post an excerpt of your file in your question (instead of a screenshot)? One or two lines should be enough.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker, perl -p -e "s/(^|\t)(?=\t|$)/${1}\t0/g" works fine.

Comment: This is strange since the `${1}` should have replaced the tab already. But it's great if you got it working anyway.

Answer (score 6):

For a tab-separated file, this AWK snippet does the trick:

```
BEGIN { FS = "\t"; OFS="\t" }
{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
         if(!$i) { $i = 0 }
    }
    print $0
}
```

Comment: Will this also work if the empty column is at the start or at the end of a line, i. e. not between two tab characters?

Comment: Yes. I've tested it on a small (3 column) file, with a fully populated row, one with a missing value in the middle, one with a missing value at the start and one with the missing at the end, and it handles all four lines correctly.

Comment: The `$0` is superfluous:  `print` is sufficient.

Comment: That's true. But I prefer to be explicit when the difference in verbosity is as small as this.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting my answer after re-reading the original post. There are no tabs as data, just delimeters. If there is no data, a double delimeter will apear to align the columns.
It can't be any other way. So if a single delimeter is there, it will separate two empty fields. "" = 1 empty field, "\t" = 2 empty fields. I got it now.

Tim Pietzcker has the correct answer all along. +1 for him.
It could be written alternatively as `s/ (?:^|(?<=\t)) (?=\t|$) /0/xg;`, but its the same thing.

Comment: The output is given by a tool and it has tab and comma option.what's the function of -i.txt here? Also my file column number can change later depending output

Comment: @berkay - c:\> perl -h  will give you all the switches. -i[extension] is in-place editing, where [extension] is added to your input filename (here its 'd.txt') as a filename for a "backup" of your input file (which is being modified). You can always run this as a Perl program and pass in the filename and number. In that case the regex would be `s!(?:^|(?<=\t))\t!$number\t!g`. Or you can do 1 liner as a batch parameter. Not sure what you are doing.

Comment: thanks but i'm having problem with the regex. s should be followed by '/, s/// is this windows style?

Comment: @berkay on unix you should use the single quote instead. This is new regex, if nothing works for you:   `perl -pe 's/(?:^|(?<=\t))(?:(?=\t$)\t|(\t))/0$1/g' d.txt`

Comment: now it works but also check the accepted answer, it's more understandable. Thanks sln. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `sed` solution. Note that some versions of `sed` don't like `\t`.

```
sed 's/^\t/0\t/;:a;s/\t\t/\t0\t/g;ta;s/\t$/\t0/' inputfile
```

or

```
sed -e 's/^\t/0\t/' -e ':a' -e 's/\t\t/\t0\t/g' -e 'ta' -e 's/\t$/\t0/' inputfile
```

Explanation:

```
s/^\t/0\t/    # insert a zero before a tab that begins a line
:a            # top of the loop
    s/\t\t/\t0\t/g    # insert a zero between a pair of tabs
ta            # if a substitution was made, branch to the top of the loop
s/\t$/\t0/    # insert a zero after a tab that ends a line
```

Comment: To clarify, a loop is needed if you have cases like `a\t\t\tb`. Regular expression matches never overlap. So if the loop is not available, `a\t\t\tb` will change to `a\t0\t\tb` and not `a\t0\t0\tb`

Answer (score 0):

If and only if your data only contains numbers and you have clear defined field separator `FS`, you can use the following trick:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) $i+=0}1' file
```

By adding zero, we convert strings to numbers. Empty strings will be converted to the number zero. You can define your field separator to anything you like.

This, however, might be a bit slow since it will reparse `$0` and split it into fields, every time you reassign a field `$i`.

A faster way is the solution of [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4663730/8344060)