# sed: Replacing empty columns with NA

Tags: awk, sed, bioinformatics, text-processing, text-parsing

I have a table of 9M rows, `snp_collection.tab` with empty values in several columns:

```
snpID   freq_bin    ID_nearest_gene ID_nearest_gene_located_within  HGNC_nearest_gene_snpsnap   HGNC_nearest_gene_snpsnap_protein_coding    flag_snp_within_gene    flag_snp_within_gene_protein_coding
10:10001753      7  ENSG00000224788                 CELF2   FALSE   FALSE
10:10001794     41  ENSG00000224788                 CELF2   FALSE   FALSE
10:100023489    10  ENSG00000138131 ENSG00000138131 LOXL4   LOXL4   TRUE    TRUE
10:100025128    45  ENSG00000138131 ENSG00000138131 LOXL4   LOXL4   TRUE    TRUE
10:10002975      1  ENSG00000224788                 CELF2   FALSE   FALSE
```

Which for simplcity, looks like this:[image]

This is messing up things when I later parse it using `awk` to produce a more useful table for my purposes:

**Later step which gets messed up from dirty input:**

```
tail -n+2 broadSNPs.tab | gawk -F'[:\t]' -vOFS="\t" '{ print "chr"$1, ($2 - 1), $2, $3, $18, $19, $20, $21}' > broadSNPs.bed
```

Here, the empty spaces aren't respected by `awk`, and rows with empty spaces are offset in the output.

So, I'm trying to fill in those empty spaces before `awk`.

Using the advice given here, [Filling space/tab separated, empty columns with 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656474/filling-space-tab-separated-empty-columns-with-0), I've done:

`sed 's/\t\t/\tNA\t/g' snp_collection.tab > broadSNPs.tab`

I have Also tried replacing the `\t`'s with `ctrl+v+tab`, but alas the output remains the same as i the original `snp_collection.tab`, with the empty spaces still just empty.

What am I missing? Thanks!

**Desired output:**

```
snpID     freq_bin  ID_nearest_gene ID_nearest_gene_located_within  HGNC_nearest_gene_snpsnap   HGNC_nearest_gene_snpsnap_protein_coding    flag_snp_within_gene    flag_snp_within_gene_protein_coding
10:10001753      7  ENSG00000224788             NA     NA   CELF2   FALSE   FALSE
10:10001794     41  ENSG00000224788             NA     NA   CELF2   FALSE   FALSE
10:100023489    10  ENSG00000138131 ENSG00000138131 LOXL4   LOXL4   TRUE    TRUE
10:100025128    45  ENSG00000138131 ENSG00000138131 LOXL4   LOXL4   TRUE    TRUE
10:10002975      1  ENSG00000224788             NA     NA   CELF2   FALSE   FALSE
```

With this fixed input, my `awk` command shouldn't produce a nonsensical output.

Comment: Please provide example file as text (not screenshot image), and expected output. Does it have to be awk/sed, maybe use R?

Comment: Just edited to provide a text example. The actual table is ~9M rows of data, so I'd like to avoid loading it into R. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution may be to tell `awk` that single tab (`\t`) is field separator:

Default behavior is for `awk` to treat any consecutive white-space as field separator:

```
echo -e "A\tB\t\tC\tD" | awk '{ print "c1="$1, "c2="$2, "c3="$3, "c4="$4, "c5="$5 }'
c1=A c2=B c3=C c4=D c5=
```

Note how `awk` treats the two consecutive tabs as single separator ie, we want `C` char to be 4th column, but it shows up as 3rd column.

Specifying single tab as separator results in column 3 being empty:

```
echo -e "A\tB\t\tC\tD" | awk -F'\t' '{ print "c1="$1, "c2="$2, "c3="$3, "c4="$4, "c5="$5 }'
c1=A c2=B c3= c4=C c5=D
```

For more information see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30406868/1515117